# PHP glob Not matching all files

Tags: php, glob

I'm trying to find out what files exist on my hdd and what files don't. I've made a script which has worked for most of the files but it's saying it can't find this file even though it's there, There are also a few others that don't work.

I have this file here, Which i've confirmed exists: 1430 - Theta (J)(Independent).nds

if i do the following:

```
$files = glob("/var/www/html/files/*");
```

I can see the file that i'm looking for, However when i try the following:

```
$findFile = glob("/var/www/html/files/1430 - Theta (J)(Independent).nds");
```

It keeps coming back as nothing found. Is there something i need to escape on this file ?

Full Code:

```
$query = "SELECT r_id, r_url FROM games WHERE r_url <> '' && r_uploaded = '' && r_console = 'nds' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {


$fileName = substr($row['r_url'], strrpos($row['r_url'], '/') + 1);

$path = "/var/www/html/files";

echo "Full URL = $row[r_url] <br />";
echo "File Name = $fileName <br />";
echo "Full Path = $path/$fileName";
echo "ID = $row[r_id] <br /> <br />";
$findFile = glob("$path/$fileName");


    if(!empty($findFile[0]) && !empty($row['r_id'])) {
        echo "File was found";      
    } else {
        echo "File not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: Okay, i've added the full code.

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump("$path/$fileName");` if you do it before your glob call?

Comment: Ah! there was a space at the end of some of the $fileName for some reason. Just did trim($fileName) and it seems to have solved it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux or Unix you need to escape the path.

```
$findFile = glob("/var/www/html/files/1430\ -\ Theta\ \(J\)\(Independent\).nds");
```

To do this better you can use the `escapeshellcmd` command. http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

```
$findFile = escapeshellcmd($findFile);
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically do this as i'm grabbing the file name from a database?

Comment: Thank you for the command, I just had an extra space at the end of $fileName though. This is solved now :)